# How to get older syntax of init(coordinates) that supports iOS 9?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have implement a function for MKMapKit:

```
let sourceMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: source.coordinate))
```

Above code works, but I get an error when I change my `Deployment Target` to iOS 9.0 to support older iOS versions. However to my surprise I got three errors, one is solved the other ones are for above code snippet. The parameter for MKPlaceholder(coordinate: ) is only supported for iOS10 or newer. Does anyone know where I can find easily the code snippet for iOS 9 that should be used instead of `coordinate` param?

The error that occurs will be: `'init(coordinate:)' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems `coordinate:addressDictionary` is nullable in [`init(coordinate:addressDictionary:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkplacemark/1451895-init).

Can't you use it like this?

```
let sourceMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: source.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil))
```